# Php strstr does not work properly

Tags: php, substring, strstr

I am trying to get rid of - in a string like 50-000 and output 50000 but unable to using strstr. Here is the code I tried

```
$addr = "50-000";
echo $addr = strtr($addr, "-", "");
```

Any clues whats going wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: `str_replace` is a lot faster than `strtr`, not that it it would probably matter in the real world

Comment: For that I referred to this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
echo str_replace('-', '', "50-000");
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

`echo str_replace("-","","50-000");`

Comment: Thanks for this but what would you suggest is wrong with strstr? Any syntax issues?

Comment: check this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

> ```
> string strtr ( string $str , string $from , string $to )
> ```
>
> If given three arguments, ... If from and to have **different lengths, the extra characters in the
>   longer of the two are ignored**. The length of str will be the same as
>   the return value's.

Since `"-"` is longer than `""`, the character is ignored.
As this three-arguments call will return the same string length, it may not help you to shorten the string from "50-000" to "50000".

Instead, you may try the two-arguments call, where the returned string length may differ:

> ```
> string strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs )
> ```

E.g.

```
$addr = "50-000";
echo $addr = strtr($addr, array("-"=>""));
// returns "50000"
```

In case you are interested to know more about `strtr()` and `str_replace()`:
[PHP strtr vs str_replace benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620549/php-strtr-vs-str-replace-benchmarking)
[When to use strtr vs str_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace)